# Flutter : How to get data from a text field and save it in a map or list for later use?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

In this page I wanted to create a text form field to ask the user to enter the name and the price of the item and then when I click on the bottom button I want to save the data in a map so I can access it from another page/widget even when I close the app or maybe to show history of transactions
What's the right way to do it ?
[the UI of the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD33s.jpg)

```
c

lass _IncomeState extends State<Income> {
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    amountController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

and this is the textfield

```
onPressed: () {
//                //this is the part where i add a new income to my list
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Add income'),
                          content: TextField(
                            autofocus: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'entrez la somme ici'),
                            controller: amountController,
                          ),
                        ));
              }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TextEditingController` to get the value entered in the `TextFormField` when the button is clicked. [Here is an example](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#2-use-a-texteditingcontroller) from the flutter homepage. Just replace the `_printLatestValue` method from the example with your saving method and call that method when pressing the button.